# Google Cloud Dataflow failing with compute.requireShieldedVm enabled

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Our company policy requires the policy contraint "compute.requireShieldedVm" to be enabled. However, when running a Cloud Dataflow job, it is failing to create a worker with the error :

Constraint constraints/compute.requireShieldedVm violated for project projects/********. The boot disk's 'initialize_params.source_image' field specifies a non-Shielded image: projects/dataflow-service-producer-prod/global/images/dataflow-dataflow-owned-resource-20200216-22-rc00. See https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints for more information."

Is there any way when running a Dataflow job to request that a ShieldedVm be used for the worker compute?

Comment: Not terribly helpful, but here is the issue tracker for tracking this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156442870

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to provide a custom image as there is no such parameter that one can provide during job submission as can be seen here [Job Submission Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params)

Alternatively, if you are running a Python based dataflow job you can setup the environment through setup files. An example of which can be found here [Dataflow - Custom Python Package Environment](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset/juliaset_main.py)

Comment: Any idea what kinds of things would go in that setup.py in the example you provided? It seems to be that Shielded VMs are part of the underlying platform and not exposed to the OS. So any commands executed in the OS would have no effect. 
https://cloud.google.com/security/shielded-cloud/shielded-vm#vtpm